# OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I'm diving into Java (this is day 1) and I'm trying to create a button that will trigger a notification when I click it...

This code is based off of the notification documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), and UI events documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

```
package com.example.contactwidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ContactWidget extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button calc1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_button_1);
        calc1.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;

    //Error: OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

            int icon = R.drawable.icon;
            CharSequence ticketBrief = "Button Pressed Brief";
            CharSequence ticketTitle = "Button pressed";
            CharSequence ticketText = "You pressed button 1";
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticketBrief, when);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ContactWidget.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), ticketTitle, ticketText, contentIntent);

            mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running into a problem: `OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type`.  The problem here is that I don't see any problems with my code in relation to the example I'm using

Comment: Sorry - I'm guessing it's java

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this import:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

If you are using Eclipse, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to make it import those clases or interfaces automagically.

Comment: Doh!  Forgot about that.... but I'm still seeing the same error on the line with `calc1.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);`

Comment: There are two interfaces called OnClickListener, make sure you import the correct one. Could you paste the error you get?

Comment: Generally eclipse suggests importing classes, why doesn't it doing that for this damn one?

Comment: Because Eclipse sucks (compared with other more intelligent IDEs like IntelliJ).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have both these imports:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Should be above the button declaration, just below

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```